# Taking Column A values comparing to Column B values if they are the same post to Column C

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to take the names from column A compare them to the names in column B and then have the similar names get listed in column C.

The problem is these names are automatically updated and out of order, and I need the function in column C to update with them. Also, the names will not be in order, this is why I can't use A=B function. The picture shown is an example of what the solution would look like or something similar. After completing this, I would like to continue using the same function to break down the name data even more. Watched a lot of videos on this, can't find anything specific enough to work.

Side note, I have found a way to do this using different pages within the sheets but not in the same sheet side by side. [ex. of what solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MDAb7.png)

I have tried watching lots of YouTube videos, but nothing goes into detail enough and seem to only explain when similar values are next to each other in column A and B.

This is what I use for 2 different sheets but can't find / understand why when changing values in function to single sheet it wont work:

```
=filter(Sheet1!A2:B,ISNUMBER(match(Sheet1!A2:A,Raid1!A2:A,0)))
```

Also, another side note: Can't use True or False. And for uneven number of names in the list ex. Column A has 10 and B has 7 it sorts A for names in B and post similar in C.

Answer (score 1):

Try below formula-

```
=FILTER(C3:C,INDEX(COUNTIFS(D3:D,C3:C))>0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use VLOOKUP to check common values between columns and store them in another column.

`=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A:A,B:B,1,false),"")`

Although this will create gaps in the output column. you can get rid of it by by simply using a filter or so.

[image: Formula]

[image: how it loks]

Answer (score 0):

all you need is:

```
=FILTER(C3:C; COUNTIFS(D3:D; C3:C))
```